# mkdocs: Using a custom python module to complement a plugin

Tags: python, mkdocs

I would like to write a plugin for mkdocs that allows to add a file of custom python code.
Here is an [example of plugin](https://github.com/rosscdh/mkdocs-markdownextradata-plugin/blob/master/markdownextradata/plugin.py).

I would like to put the module in the website's main dir, alongside the `mkdocs.yml` file, and declare that module in there, e.g.:

```
python_module=mycode.py
```

Then I would use in the code of the plugin, something like:

```
from mkdocs.plugins import BasePlugin

from jinja2 import Template
import importlib

class MarkdownExtraDataPlugin(BasePlugin):
    "Execute piece of code"

    def on_page_markdown(self, markdown, page, config, site_navigation, **kwargs):

        python_module = config.get('python_module')

        if python_module:
            # Add path, here is the question:
            python_module = os.path.join(*?????*, python_module)

            # do import here:
            importlib.import_module(python_module)

        ....
        return result
```

The problem I am having at this point is I don't know how the code of the module could know the location of the yaml file, or the location of the markdown file. By any chance, would that be part of the `config` dictionary?

#### Update

I wrote the plugin and [made it available on github](https://github.com/fralau/mkdocs_macros_plugin). Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on which version of MkDocs you are using. In [#1376](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/pull/1376) the path was added to the config object as the attribute `config.config_file_path`. However, that won't be available until the next release ([1.0](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/milestone/4)). Regardless, earlier versions include an undocumented [config option](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/blob/0.17/mkdocs/config/defaults.py#L17) `config['config_file_path']` which holds the location of the file. Be careful however, as any undocumented features are subject to change without notice.

As for the location of the Markdown file, that is available in [various attributes](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/blob/0.17/mkdocs/nav.py#L168-L172) of the [page](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/custom-themes/#page) object passed to the plugin event. You have your pick of `page.input_path`, `page.output_path`, `page.abs_input_path`, and `page.abs_output_path`. Again, these are undocumented and subject to change in a future release without notice. In fact, [#1504](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/pull/1504) proposes changing them to `page.file.src_path`, `page.file.dest_path`, `page.file.abs_src_path`, and `page.file.abs_dest_path` for the 1.0 release. But that's the risk in working against pre-1.0 software. Things change as the developers try to get it right. The good news is that the 1.0 release will lock these things down going forward.

Full disclosure: I am a member of the MkDocs development team.

Comment: thanks a lot for this excellent answer. It is good to have a member of the development team answer that question! Just curious, is there already a place where those attributes are documented?

Comment: No, they are not documented because we are not ready to commit to anything yet. Of course, as the Plugin API is new (last release), there hasn't been any need to document them previously (compare with the page attributes used by theme authors, which have been documents for some time). Once we get the 1.0 behavior nailed down, then we'll be adding more documentation that will be useful to Plugin developers. For now, it's mostly browsing the source code.